# How to choose correct prepositions for the word 'difference'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

For the following question, is the preposition 'with' necessary? Can I just delete it? Or can I replace it with another preposition 'in'?

The biggest difference, however, was **with** reputation; approximately 68% of the younger ones mentioned it in the survey.This percentage was almost quadruple that of the older (around 18%).

Comment: What differences is the passage talking about - between what and what?

Comment: To my ear, "in" is preferable to the original. There might be regional differences, though, as in British English, "different to" is preferred, and in the U.S., "different from". See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/different-from-different-to-or-different-than